Family of probability distributions on $\{0, 1, \ldots, n\}$ that can approximate any deterministic distribution
Consider a family $\mathscr{F}$ of probability distributions with the following properties:

$\mathscr{F}$ can be parameterized by a discrete parameter $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and, for some fixed $d \in \mathbb{N}$, continuous parameters $a_1, \ldots, a_d \in \mathbb{R}$. I'm especially interested in the case where $d = 2$.
Each $D \in \mathscr{F}$ has support $[n] = \{0, 1, \ldots, n - 1\}$.
$\mathscr{F}$ has as limit points as all $n$ deterministic distributions on $\mathcal{X}$. That is, it can concentrate probability mass on any element of $[n]$ arbitrarily well.

What are some examples of such families in the literature?

I am not familiar with literature on this, but is the following idea possible? We consider Gaussian distribution with mean $a_1$ and variance $a^2_2$, then we consider the pdf on $[n]$ and normalize it. Then, for each $i \in [n]$, as $a_1 \to i$ and $a_2 \to 0$, the distribution approaches the deterministic distribution on $i$.

@VezenBU Yes. One could also rescale the beta distribution, which has finite support, from $[0, 1]$ to $[0, n-1]$ and apply the same method. But I was wondering if there were any more "natural" examples in the literature.

Can you be more specific about "natural"?

@VezenBU It's an informal notion, but one possible defining feature is having a concise sampling method/generative story/combinatorial interpretation, as the discrete uniform, binomial, beta-binomial, hypergeometric, and negative hypergeometric distributions do.
